# Why does App Engine not like Spring's ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

Why does App Engine choke on this Spring code?

```
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
    Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("com/freshlyorc/datamodelbeans");
    for (BeanDefinition component : components){
        Class cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
        results.add(cls);
    }
```

Every other time I run this code on App Engine, it says something such as:

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chapstick' defined in file [/base/data/home/apps/s~freshlyorc/1.00/WEB-INF/classes/com/freshlyorc/datamodelbeans/Chapstick.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.freshlyorc.datamodelbeans.Chapstick] failed; nested exception is com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
```

Is `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` too resource-heavy? Is there a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine only allows Whitelisted libraries. This part of the Spring library might now be on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine currently does not allow any request to take more than 60 seconds to complete. The DeadlineExceededException is thrown to tell you that your time is up. It is possible to catch the exception in order to buy yourself some time to clean up any loose ends, but execution will soon be killed.

The classpath scanning and reflection performed by Spring is indeed a slow process. Unless you're adding to the classpath at runtime, you should be fine performing this work once as part of building your application, saving the result to a file which you can load later.